# Git ignore this kind of files?

Tags: git, gitignore

How can I ignore files like this one

```
.tmp_index.html.36436~
```

Comment: You need to be more specific with what you mean by "like this one". When you define what set of files you want to include and exclude, then you will know what pattern you need to add to your .gitignore file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the pattern in your .gitignore file.

```
*~
```

Comment: +1 -- much more direct and should cover all the files that his text editor generates.

Answer (score 3):

The .gitignore file can take wildcards, so you could do something like

```
echo ".tmp_index.html.*~" >> .gitignore
```

Comment: +1 for demo-ing how to create a `.gitignore` file (Windows GUI editors and Explorer will not let you *create* such a file any other way that I know of.)

Comment: @Sean: Do you mean because of their default setting to hide file extensions? I remember being able to create a new text file from explorer or launch notepad and save as just fine, but I don't have a system to test on now.

Comment: To create the file with notepad. When you enter the save as box, make sure to put quotes around the filename. such as  ".gitignore" This will allow you to create the file w/o what windows thinks is a filename.

Answer (score 1):

That depends a bit on what all file names can be generated.  Based on the example though it looks like you want to ignore files which begin with the `.tmp_index.html` prefix.  If so then add the following to your .gitignore file

> .tmp_index.html*

Answer (score 0):

Add a file named `.gitignore` to the root directory of the folder that contains your git repository and add this line into it:

```
*.tmp*
```